# Is `Pair` a valid instance of `MonadRec`?

Tags: typescript, monads, tail-recursion, purescript, fantasyland

In the paper [Stack Safety for Free](https://functorial.com/stack-safety-for-free/index.pdf), Phil Freeman defines the `MonadRec` type class as follows.

```hs
class (Monad m) <= MonadRec m where
  tailRecM :: forall a b. (a -> m (Either a b)) -> a -> m b
```

An instance of the `MonadRec` class must satisfy the following laws.

1. `tailRecM f a` must be equivalent to `f a >>= go` where `go (Left a) = f a >>= go` and `go (Right b) = pure b`.
2. The stack usage of `tailRecM f` must be at most a constant multiple of the stack usage of `f` itself.

Now, consider the following `Pair` class in TypeScript.

```js
class Pair<out A> {
  public constructor(
    public readonly fst: A,
    public readonly snd: A,
  ) {}

  public chain<A, B>(this: Pair<A>, arrow: (value: A) => Pair<B>): Pair<B> {
    return new Pair(arrow(this.fst).fst, arrow(this.snd).snd);
  }

  public static of<A>(value: A): Pair<A> {
    return new Pair(value, value);
  }
}
```

As you can see, `Pair` is a valid monad. Now, I want to define the `chainRec` function for `Pair`, which is the [Fantasy Land](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land) equivalent of the `tailRecM` function defined by Phil Freeman. For simplicity, I first define my own `Either` type.

```js
class Left<out A> {
  public readonly isLeft = true;

  public constructor(public readonly value: A) {}
}

class Right<out B> {
  public readonly isLeft = false;

  public constructor(public readonly value: B) {}
}

type Either<A, B> = Left<A> | Right<B>;
```

And then, I defined the `chainRec` function as follows inside the `Pair` class.

```js
public static chainRec<A, B>(
  arrow: (value: A) => Pair<Either<A, B>>,
  value: A,
): Pair<B> {
  const rec = (either: Either<A, B>): Pair<B> => {
    const stack: Either<B, Either<A, B>>[] = [];

    let cursor: Either<Either<A, B>, Pair<B>> = new Left(either);

    while (stack.length > 0 || cursor.isLeft) {
      if (cursor.isLeft) {
        const either: Either<A, B> = cursor.value;
        if (either.isLeft) {
          const pair = arrow(either.value);
          cursor = new Left(pair.fst);
          stack.push(new Right(pair.snd));
        } else cursor = new Right(Pair.of(either.value));
      } else {
        const pair: Pair<B> = cursor.value;
        const frame = stack.pop()!;
        if (frame.isLeft) cursor = new Right(new Pair(frame.value, pair.snd));
        else {
          cursor = new Left(frame.value);
          stack.push(new Left(pair.fst));
        }
      }
    }

    return cursor.value;
  };

  return arrow(value).chain(rec);
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&noUnusedLocals=true&noUnusedParameters=true&target=99&jsx=0&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&noFallthroughCasesInSwitch=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature=true&allowUnusedLabels=true#code/MYGwhgzhAEAyCmAzALgHgPYFdnQIID5oBvAKGmgAdMAjEAS2GgCd4wATdAOxAE9o6ICFNAC80ZE0zwA3CTKUa9RsC4QJmYMnRMAFFVoNmrDtz4A3MCCkAuPAEpiAXxLOSoSDABKdAOYALNCwcACFCUnJ9JSN2Ll5+QSQcMURLCBk5CMVDFU41SU1tPSzGFhjTaAsreFtghyJnV2QeCnhoAFE6ZD94JlRcABpoUNE4RL7CAB9ob380UNk3cChoAAUwOl6gvDD5SOzVdQLdeUyDEuNYvkQ1WwGThTPokziITjZb-vk611Oo4D91pw+oNQjougJbGsNuNBmAmEx0AB3Ww6So2eyiQhQ3qhOyQ9Y4nbkcgsZCYJicaCceCI1YEnRwhGIsF+AQAOmuyDsHLUsPhSJZ7NebG5wrssnIPweUTUYGQhnQiHGqMs6NweLp0IIxHupPJlOptOxKqqgzR8HF8ile0YsvlygBdE4nngwGBQ3wOnujKRKPNtwcIixBNQHS6PXdoXwn2JFVV1TwMegGuxqGG4WJOTURkYYh08E63SYtjDRcj+BTIeGQZ1sfIWZwsuAAGsS4WI8FBqWIwMPfgANoAXRGQ4WdegIHgOGA5Ig2jb4d63d6vdCg1TUZGhtGKHz7aYlvu5ERrMn0B0TebbMnnB8XWghAADNAJlMZ0w50w2QIhFza+P+EQc930-b8EhQOojzrBtoALRcFzLVdCDEEDtDZc0JQA8g6CAvdFzA39IKw2MYIoAkRh9Zk4KLdD40tYjM1nbQtxpHdkD0AkeS5TCGMvNkqAgPwdG3GYAg4jY2TFejiMcWCQDSaBUKYFjaVE9jsTZRU8Jo807Gk8dZPgeTWgzLDSIJfFoWrRSmK-DCoJIg5oEQJgwAAW1aMQ+IodAKB0OwAEIeIAnDzxc9z4AIxIHCUlTpl8MTt2NcKPNo01KE4qTgvHIyFNM4jYrEbdfx0FLIt07KAO8zBBOE1iSrIiTOT0yrY2cLD2rrKVYz1CkbI-ND7LasdiV6ylKJNKRuX+QEdBYYBpIaEggA)

It's easy to prove that this implementation of `chainRec` satisfies the first law. `Pair.chainRec(f, a)` is equivalent to

```js
f(a).chain(function go(either) {
  return either.isLeft ? f(either.value).chain(go) : Pair.of(either.value);
});
```

However, I'm not sure whether it satisfies the second law.

- The stack usage of `Pair.chainRec(f, a)` must be at most a constant multiple of the stack usage of `f` itself.

I'm unsure because the `rec` function has a local `stack` variable which can grow arbitrarily large. Granted, the `stack` lives on the heap and only a reference to the `stack` lives on the stack. So, in that sense it does satisfy the second law. However, if we allow the `chainRec` function to use an arbitrarily large *local* stack then wouldn't we be able to create a valid instance of `MonadRec` for every possible monad? If the answer is no, then what are some example types that are valid instances of `Monad` but not valid instances of `MonadRec`? That is, what are some examples of monads which are not tail recursive?